# How can I preserve padding as an element boundary in a contenteditable div?

Tags: html, css

I have an contenteditable div in which I have a span with background and padding.

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
      Blah content <span style="background:#efefef; padding:8px">my span</span> and some more content
</div>
```

However, per the above snippet when I move the cursor from the end of `content` to the beginning of `my` the caret jumps **inside** the padding (Chrome 80.0.3987.132).

When going the other way backwards, moving the caret from the start of `and` to the end of `span`, it respects the padding and does not move inside it.

How can I preserve the padding as a boundary for the element?

Comment: Should you add padding in ```<div contenteditable="true">```

Comment: no, the padding is on the span only as a UI guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate the left padding using a hidden character where you apply a `letter-spacing`

```css
div {
  font-size: 50px;
}

span {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

span:before {
  content: "a"; /* anything here */
  font-size: 0;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  Blah content <span>my span</span> and some more content
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great way to do it! Most approaches that use padding or margin don't update the caret position, this works perfectly for spans in (or next to) content-editable fields.

I'm currently using this in custom css in Obsidian to fix misaligned carets next to bullet points from the Outliner plugin. Here's the snippet: `.outliner-plugin-better-lists .cm-formatting-list-ul { margin: 0; letter-spacing: 3px; }`

Answer (score 1):

The cursor sits in the front of a character, from the left side there's a space between content and the span the cursor is sitting in from of the space from the left side, the same thing happens on the other side but it looks differently because after the end of the span there a space which the cursor sits in front of.

**Preview:**

[image]

I don't think you can change this.